# How to override flexbox justify-content: space-between?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to override `space-between` so that the last item would horizontally align to the next to last? Or should I just drop `space-between` and go with `flex-start` and custom margins?

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ta2ewLjn/2/)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.item {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #111;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.next-to-last {
  background-color: blue;
}
.last-item {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item next-to-last"></div>
  <div class="item last-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the container is a fixed-width (like in your code) then the simplest solution is to use `flex-start` and custom margins, like you said.

Answer (score 0):

**Fake element method:**

You can add a fake element for the 4th item so that 5 and 6 are next to each other.

This will work if you use `visibility: hidden` to hide the element and preserve the space occupied by it. The common alternative `display: none` *will not work* since the item is not calculated in the flexbox alignment.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.item {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #111;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.next-to-last {
  background-color: blue;
}
.last-item {
  background-color: red;
}
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item invisible"></div> <!-- Invisible fake element -->
  <div class="item next-to-last"></div>
  <div class="item last-item"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Custom margin method:**

If you don't want to create an additional element then you need to use your own suggestion of `flex-start` and custom margin.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.item {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #111;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.next-to-last {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.last-item {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item next-to-last"></div>
  <div class="item last-item"></div>
</div>
```